# Ruby on Rails friendly_id, babosa gems, problems with transliteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id, transliteration

I'm using the gems: `friendly_id, babosa`.

Model **product.rb**:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
   has_many :tags

   def normalize_friendly_id(input)
    input.to_s.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
   end

end
```

I launched сonsole, to generate slugs for existing products:

```
Product.find_each(&:save)
```

Checking the last item:

```
Product.last

#<Product id: 4972, name: "ВА 47-63, 2P 2А (C) EKF", created_at: "2016-01-27 11:32:39", updated_at: "2016-01-27 11:32:39", slug: 04b4aa2d-2bb9-46f9-8d49-cbb9d0c3f872">
```

But transliteration is wrong. I'm trying doing same in console:

```
"ВА 47-63, 2P 2А (C) EKF".to_s.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
=> "va-47-63-2p-2a-c-ekf"
```

Now its normal result. I can not understand why this is so.

In the same way did transliteration for the tags, she received adequate.

Model **tag.rb**:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  belongs_to :product

  def normalize_friendly_id(input)
   input.to_s.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean `transliteration is wrong.`? What value has the `input`?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by replacing function on model `product.rb`:

```
"input.to_s.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s" ->
"input.to_slug.normalize! :transliterations => [:russian]"
```

on my Model it is:

```
def normalize_friendly_id(text)
    text.to_slug.normalize! :transliterations => [:vietnamese]
end
```